# Custom renderer breaking site

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to the DJango world, having just started up my first Python job a few months ago (PHP dev for the last decade). I'm working with Django REST API on an endpoint where I need to return an XML string, but from looking around, seems like none of the built in renderers allow you to simply pass a string to be returned as is?

I saw that `HTTPResponse` works, but `Response` doesn't, and a coworker told me that `Response` is a better choice and to create a renderer. I thought it seemed pretty simple based on source code, with basically this being the bare minimum:

```
class PassThroughRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = None
    format = None

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

My view (trimmed a bit, but only some model storage):

```
def post(self, request):
    original_soap = request.body
    try:
        parsed_soap = xmltodict.parse(original_soap)
    except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError:
        return Response(dicttoxml({'invalid_xml': True}), content_type='text/xml', status=422)
    parsed_soap = self.strip_sf_prefix(parsed_soap)

    config = yaml.load(settings.SALESFORCE_CRED)
    organization_id = config['organization_id']

    if parsed_soap['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['notifications']['OrganizationId'] != organization_id:
        return Response(dicttoxml({'unauthorized': True}), content_type='text/xml', status=401)

    return Response(SALESFORCE_RESPONSE, content_type='text/xml')
```

Unfortunately, when I run that (having added `renderer_classes = (utils.PassThroughRenderer,)` to my APIView class), I get `'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'` and a traceback that doesn't seem to hit any code I've written.

Comment: Can you show your view also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Done. Sorry I didn't include it from the start, didn't think it would be too important, but I can see why it is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had to explicitly set `media_type` to a non `None` value. Setting a default (which I'm overriding anyway) allowed the renderer to run.